# iOS: Error - 23 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

Looking at similar questions and answers, this error message seems that it could stem from a variety of different areas.  Hopefully someone can help me figure out my problem.  I am getting this error when running on the simulator, no problems with running on a device.

**Error Message**

```
ld: 23 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

**Details**

This seems to have started when I added the Twitter API.  All of the error messages either say one of the following:

```
duplicate symbol _STTwitterAppOnlyErrorCode in:

duplicate symbol _STTwitterAPIErrorCode in:

duplicate symbol _STTwitterHTMLErrorCode in:

duplicate symbol _STTwitterOSErrorCode in:

duplicate symbol _STTwitterOAuthErrorCode in:
```

**What I have done so far is:**

1) Looked for duplicate files, there are none

2) Looked for duplicate #import statements, there are none

3) Checked if I did a #import on a .m file, I did not

4) I do not have -ObjC in Other Linker Flags

So does anyone have an idea as to what I can do to get rid of this error message?

Comment: Have you checked on build phases for duplicates?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to be any duplicates.  You can't order them alphabetically but I didn't see any duplicate files.  In my Copy Bundle Resources Main.storyboard is red, could that be a problem?

Comment: No, I don't think that's your problem. Maybe some other API you use also uses Twitter API?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How could I check to see if that was my problem?

Comment: I don't think is very likely, but I don't have any other ideas. Maybe some other lib you use also defines these symbols

Comment: I have libz.dylib and libxml2.dylib in my project, that is it though. I can't remember what I needed to add those for, though.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the ST API? I notice a comment that some `NS_ENUM` definitions in the header files were changed to `extern NS_ENUM` to avoid duplicate symbols. https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/pull/189/files. Seems like your issue?

Comment: RORY!!!!! You sir, are a genius.  That solved my issue, please put this as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. Good end for a Firday 8^). Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of the ST API?

I notice a comment that some NS_ENUM definitions in the header files were changed to extern NS_ENUM to avoid duplicate symbols.

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/pull/189/files

Seems like your issue?